# Why can't I use np.where and str.contains to assign categories?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to assign each description to a category, however I keep getting an error. I am pretty new to python, so any help figuring this out is much appreciated!

|  | Date | Description | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 8/11/2023 | vending machine | -2.40 | unassigned |
| 1 | 8/14/2023 | christianacare | -155.00 | unassigned |
| 2 | 8/14/2023 | shakeshack | -33.56 | unassigned |
| 3 | 8/14/2023 | capitalone | -317.14 | unassigned |
| 4 | 8/15/2023 | nordproducts | -18.28 | unassigned |

```
#Assign transactions to the correct category

# Bills
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('christianacare',
  'capitalone', 'usaa', 'zelle'), 'Bills', df['Category'])
# Food
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('vending machine',
  'tacobell', 'shakeshack', 'univlqr', 'gridiron', 'starbucks'), 'Food', df['Category'])
# Shopping
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('amazon'), 'Shopping', df['Category'])
# Services
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('coursera',
  'empowerme', 'albert', 'apple', 'peacock', 'nordproducts', 'patreon'), 'Services', df['Category'])
# Entertainment
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('playstation',
  'microsoft'), 'Entertainment', df['Category'])
# Transport
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('parkmobile'), 'Transport', df['Category'])
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 5
      1 #Assign transactions to the correct category
      2 
      3 # Bills
----> 5 df['Category'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('christianacare',
      6   'capitalone', 'usaa', 'zelle'), 'Bills', df['Category'])
      8 # Food
     10 df['Category'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('vending machine',
     11   'tacobell', 'shakeshack', 'univlqr', 'gridiron', 'starbucks'), 'Food', df['Category'])

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py:129, in forbid_nonstring_types.<locals>._forbid_nonstring_types.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    124     msg = (
    125         f"Cannot use .str.{func_name} with values of "
    126         f"inferred dtype '{self._inferred_dtype}'."
    127     )
    128     raise TypeError(msg)
--> 129 return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py:1260, in StringMethods.contains(self, pat, case, flags, na, regex)
   1252 if regex and re.compile(pat).groups:
   1253     warnings.warn(
   1254         "This pattern is interpreted as a regular expression, and has "
   1255         "match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.",
   1256         UserWarning,
   1257         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
   1258     )
-> 1260 result = self._data.array._str_contains(pat, case, flags, na, regex)
   1261 return self._wrap_result(result, fill_value=na, returns_string=False)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\object_array.py:122, in ObjectStringArrayMixin._str_contains(self, pat, case, flags, na, regex)
    119     if not case:
    120         flags |= re.IGNORECASE
--> 122     pat = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
    124     f = lambda x: pat.search(x) is not None
    125 else:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\__init__.py:227, in compile(pattern, flags)
    225 def compile(pattern, flags=0):
    226     "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a Pattern object."
--> 227     return _compile(pattern, flags)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\__init__.py:287, in _compile(pattern, flags)
    285 if not _compiler.isstring(pattern):
    286     raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
--> 287 if flags & T:
    288     import warnings
    289     warnings.warn("The re.TEMPLATE/re.T flag is deprecated "
    290               "as it is an undocumented flag "
    291               "without an obvious purpose. "
    292               "Don't use it.",
    293               DeprecationWarning)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'RegexFlag'
```

I tried to use `str.match` instead of `str.contains`. I was expecting for each category to be assigned to specific descriptions. So when I look at the dataset, the category column would be filled out automatically.

Comment: The first argument to `.contains` should be regular expression pattern. You use single strings for each separate argument, which doesn't work. Please see [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

Comment: Did you mean to check containment the opposite way, on a set of strings? `df['Description'].isin({'christianacare', 'capitalone', 'usaa', 'zelle'})`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. If my or 97's comments don't answer your question, please [edit] to clarify. Walking us through your train of thought would help, since it's not clear why exactly you were expecting it to work. Plus, the error occurs before `np.where` even runs, so you can discard that aspect entirely. For more tips, see [ask] and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. Also if it helps, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: `.str.contains` checks for substring/pattern, for example `.str.contains('usaa|zelle')`, and will return `True` for `'Some usaa'`. You might want to use `.isin` if you want to match the entire cell value. Also `.map` is another option if you have to replace a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is usin `.isin`:

```py
mapping = {
    'Bills': {'capitalone', 'christianacare', 'usaa', 'zelle'},
    'Food': {'gridiron', 'shakeshack', 'starbucks', 'tacobell', 'univlqr', 'vending machine'},
    'Shopping': {'amazon'},
    'Services': {'albert', 'apple', 'coursera', 'empowerme', 'nordproducts', 'patreon', 'peacock'},
    'Entertainment': {'microsoft', 'playstation'},
    'Transport': {'parkmobile'}
}

for k, v in mapping.items():
    df["Category"] = np.where(df["Description"].isin(v), k, df["Category"])

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        Date      Description  Amount  Category
0  8/11/2023  vending machine   -2.40      Food
1  8/14/2023   christianacare -155.00     Bills
2  8/14/2023       shakeshack  -33.56      Food
3  8/14/2023       capitalone -317.14     Bills
4  8/15/2023     nordproducts  -18.28  Services
```